# How to modify my login to verify email?

Tags: django

I have already used login class

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
  username = forms.CharField()
  password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

And views file of my app

```
from .forms import LoginForm

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(username=cd['username'],password=cd['password'])

        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('Authenticated!')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'account/login.html', {'form': form})
```

([hunter](https://hunter.io/api/docs#email-verifier)) provides email verifier.This is HTTP request example

```
GET https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-verifier?email=steli@close.io
```

How to modify my login and views files?

Comment: when exactly you want to verify email on registration?

Comment: May be at the very beginning of user_login after I instantiate the form.

Comment: @RichardRublev you need to send a GET request to hunter API with the email address that your user filled in your login form? Is this correct?

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos Yes,that is right.

Comment: i would say making a decorator would be nice option and add it to login function

Comment: I agree but my request method is GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the code below :

```
import urllib2
get_request = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-verifier?email=' + username)
```

then the `get_request` variable will contain a JSON object as mentioned in hunter documentation.

the `get_request` will be added in after the `cd = form.cleaned_data`